# <a href preventDefault works every second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a trash icon which user clicks on to delete current element from database. I want to make it work with `ajax` if user has `javascript` enabled. There are multiple items on page.

Don't know why but even after adding `preventDefault`, `href` works like regular `href` instead of performing `ajax`. It triggers `ajax` request without refreshing window only every second time I click on trash icon.

Do you know where is the problem?

```js
$('.delete_bulletin').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('event');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr('href')).done(
            function () {
                reloadBoardContent();
            }
    );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bulletin_board">
    <div class="bulletin_card">
        <i>4. apríl 2018 14:50</i>
        <h4>NAME</h4>
        <p></p><p>htrhr</p><p></p>
        <a class="delete_bulletin" href="/bulletin-board/delete/35/"><img style="max-height: 20px" src="/static/bulletin_board/icons/trash.png"></a>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="bulletin_card">
        <i>4. apríl 2018 14:49</i>
        <h4>NAME</h4>
        <p></p><p>fdsafdfs</p><p></p>
        <a class="delete_bulletin" href="/bulletin-board/delete/34/"><img style="max-height: 20px" src="/static/bulletin_board/icons/trash.png"></a>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Just as a note, having something like a "delete" operation work when requested by an HTTP "GET" operation is just asking for trouble.

Comment: You can set `href="javascript:void(0)"` to the `<a>`, or simply use a `<button>` instead of anchor.

Comment: preventDefault and stopPropagation ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation ) are tricky -- it may just be the console call to print out 'event' that's slowing things down long enough for things to go wonky.  Could you just use a button instead of a link?

Comment: also (before the edits) I saw no document.ready() wrapped around the event binding; but try it with delegated events too

Comment: also, you have an anonymous function calling a named function for no reason, just pass the named function to your done method. `$.get($(this).attr('href')).done(reloadBoardContent);`

Comment: All you need is someone with a prefetch script loaded and they wipe your database. You should be using proper verbs for operations. You should be making a DELETE request, not a GET.

Comment: @Pointy It has to work as a regular request and XHR too. Could you elaborate why it is asking for trouble?

Comment: Anybody can code a GET request into a hostile website that could perform the delete operation. It's called Cross-Site Request Forgery, or CSRF, and using GET instead of POST makes it much much easier to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure (but needs confirmation) that your `reloadBoardContent()` is updating the `div` where this `<a>` is located.

If that's the case, the anchor will be replaced and the event won't trigger to the newly created ones.

The solution is to use delegate events, which will make it work for dynamically added elements.

Do this instead:

```
$('#bulletin_board').on('click', '.delete_bulletin', function (e) {
```

If you don't replace the `<div id="bulletin_board"` itself but only its contents, everything shall be fine from now on.